# LINQ-To-SQL OrderBy with DateTime Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have this LINQ query.  The date is stored as a string in the database, but I need to order by it.  So I convert it to a DateTime, but it doesn't order.

```
   (from m in dbDataContext.TimeCards
    where m.TIMECARDDATE != ""
    && m.TIMECARDDATE != null
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(m.TIMECARDDATE) descending
    select Convert.ToDateTime(m.TIMECARDDATE)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? I can't change the database, so I have to deal with the data the way it is. I get the data back ordered like this...

```
 2/27/2009
 2/26/2009
 2/25/2009
 2/28/2009
 2/24/2009
```

Comment: first you may use string.IsNullOrEmpty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try evaluating the expression without sorting, and then apply the sort to the results of Distinct:

```
(Linq-To-Sql-Expression).Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.TIMECARDDATE).ToList()
```

Comment: Distinct() does not guarantee that it will maintain the order of the items that went into it - just that it will return a distinct result set. So although the input to Distinct() was originally sorted properly, its output was not.

Answer (score 1):

First you may use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, instead of checking whether the string is null or `""`

Beside, this should work. You probably reorder it outside of this code.

Pay attention this isn't execute until you foreach it (call `GetEnumerator()`).
So if you change something before iterating it.. that might be the reason.

p.s. is TIMECARDDATE is object or string?

Comment: It's actually executed when that line is executed because I am using the .ToList() which causes it to be evaluated at that time.  

TIMECARDDATE is a string.(sadly)

Comment: also, string.IsNullOrEmpty is not supported in LINQ-To-SQL

Comment: i haven't noticed the ToList, and there is nothing to do with LINQ to SQL.... you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty on any string.