# mvc-Passing query data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i want to show my data from DB with query.
now i see the data but it show all  table (dog) and i dont 
successful combain query.

i want add query for display the dog_num from the smallest to grow

```
select * from dog order By dog_num desc
```

my code:

**view**

```
     <table class="table">
        <tr>
   <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dog_num)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dog_name)
            </th>

     </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
   <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dog_num)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dog_name)
                </td>


     </tr>
```

**controller**

```
 private model db = new model();

        public ActionResult Index()
            {


            return View(db.dog.ToList());

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alex, this is very simple

You need to choose a Property to sort by and pass it as a lambda expression to OrderByDescending

**like:**

.OrderByDescending(x => x.dog_num);

Example:

**your Tsql:**

select * from dog order By dog_num desc

**Equivalent linq:**

```
db.dog.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.dog_num);
```

Final controller code:

private model db = new model();

```
    public ActionResult Index()
        {


        return View(db.dog.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.dog_num));

        }
```

Hope this is what you want ,kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks
karthik

Comment: if i want to do same but with date is not workin because is take the "day" only. 02/01/17 and 05/04/16 , 02/01/17 will appear  firsrt because 02 is smaller than 05 but is not the  earliest date. you know how to fix that?

Comment: My pleasure and happy that it helped. 

And to Sort the date you may try like this:
db.dog.Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.anyfieldname).ToList();
link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1620924/3397630
Hope it will help for you..:)Happy sharing